# cassandra on a single physical node

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I was hoping somebody could clarify something conceptual, I've looked around for answers but this thing is still not totally clear to me.

I'm running on a 16-core machine that has access to an external disk, mounted on /cassandra , which  has been set as the data directory on the cassandra .yaml config file. I create a KEYSPACE with a replication factor of 3.

My question is, is Cassandra still operating like a "distributed" database from the point of view of performance? It's still one single physical node, so I'm not sure what is going on there. It would seem like one is still limited by the I/O of the one disk.

The purpose is to run spark on top of Cassandra, if that helps.

I hope the question makes sense, if feels rather vague.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not acting like a distributed database meaning the data will not be replicated even though your replication factor is set to 3, if that is what you are asking. This is only  a single node setup. This article explains it better. http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/cassandra-faq-can-i-start-with-a-single-node/